# Display content in a Div and then hide it after some time

Tags: php

I have series of questions that need to be answered using a likert scale *(Strongly Disagree - Disagree - Partially Agree - Agree - Strongly Agree)*. what I want is that each question should be displayed in a div which will be disappeared after some time (say 15 sec). The person has to answer the question within time, after answering the next question will arrive in same div for same time (15 sec). 
How it should be implemented?? (implementing in Codeigniter Environment)

Comment: You Need to Use Jquery To Implement These Kind of Stuffs

Comment: use jquery and javascript from client side

Comment: Jquery will surely help but i need help in code? if you understand what i have to follow to achieve goal

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of Questions. Then make a interval of 15 seconds that change the div's content. I assume you want random Questions  , Meanwhile you have to integrate your answering functionality.

Hopefully it helps you for disappearing question and add new question randomly.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready( function() {
var Questions = [
    "Question 01",
    "Question 02",
    "Question 03",
    "Question 04",
    "Question 05",
    "Question 06",
    "Question 07",
    "Question 08",
    "Question 09"
];

// get a random index, get the value from array and
// change the div content
setInterval(function() {
    var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * Questions.length);
    if (i == Questions.length) --i;
    $("#question").html(Questions[i]);
}, 15 * 1000)
      });
    </script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="question" > </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: That's I have used a prompt box to display my question and just trying to handle the answer options, Thanks :)

Comment: Great! up vote if helped.. :) & post your sample code where your facing to handling answer options.

Comment: @Ali Harris Please accept the answer if helped thanks!! :)